# Node.js app stops working as soon as the AWS Lightsail's Bitnami console is closed

Tags: node.js, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have developed a simple node.js application and I am trying to publish it on AWS Lightsail. I followed the instructions on this page: https://medium.com/@sharmasha2nk/aws-lightsail-bitnami-nodejs-letsencrypt-cf653573b8a1
I am connecting to Bitnami using the SHH console provided. After I start the app with node index.js command the app is up and running until I close the SHH console. As soon as I close it the application stops and “Service Unavailable” error is being displayed. How can I keep my app running on AWS even if my PC is shot down and the SHH console is closed?

I have tried restarting the apache server and AWS Lightsail instance. Neither of them helped.

httpd-app.conf file content: 
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/ 
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/

httpd-prefix.conf file content: 
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/emsnotes/conf/httpd-app.conf"

Thanks.

Comment: Install screen and run your application over it, so when you close the SSH your application won't be closed. Edit: apg-get install screen, yum install screen etc.

Comment: Dear Tuğberk Bey, thanks a lot for your reply. I have tried Karim's recommendation and it worked pretty well. In case of any problems in the future, I will also try your approach.

Comment: You're welcome Ali Efe Bey. Best of luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)

Here's how to do it quickly:

1. install `pm2` globally using `sudo npm i -g pm2`
2. navigate to the location of your `index.js` via `ssh`
3. run `pm2 start index.js`

This will keep node running even when you disconnect the ssh session or shutdown your development computer. The process will keep running on your server in the background. This is used for running node apps in production on a server.

You can read all about it here in its [documentation](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/).

I hope I could help you, please let me know if you have any question.

Karim

Comment: Dear Karim, thanks a lot  for your reply. It worked! I spent hours on this issue before posting this question here, and your reply solved it in a minute.

Comment: you're very welcome and thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the article and frankly i see nowhere that he talk about keeping the server up and running.

Basically he is using the Bitnami Node.js stack and if you look at the docs you will see that Bitnami use Forever.js to keep the apps running on their instance, Forever is a CLI tool to monitor and keep a Node instance running in the background.

Check the docs here : https://docs.bitnami.com/general/infrastructure/nodejs/administration/start-express-server/

Here is the Git for Forever, so can read more on it: https://github.com/foreverjs/forever

Comment: I didn't know what was the latest trends, are people running PM2 ,Forever or an other one ...  You just needed something to make the process run in the background but which one is better i don't know.